# Is there any way to get wikipedia pageview statistics per page at the *country* grain (instead of simply language)?

Tags: wikipedia, wikimedia, wikimedia-dumps

I see dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/, for example, but no country-specific data there...

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there isn't.  For obvious privacy reasons, the published page view statistics don't include any IP address information, so there's no way to tell *where* the requests are coming from.

That said, I suppose it *might* be possible for the [WMF Analytics Team](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Analytics) to provide such statistics, or at least some rough approximation of them, if enough people were to request them.  [Apparently](https://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Privacy_policy/FAQ#inferlocationFAQ), Wikimedia does already have an IP geolocation database that they use for other purposes (e.g. local event notifications and fundraising campaigns), so that part might not be as hard as it could otherwise seem.  There might still be issues with the sheer request volume and potential privacy leaks (e.g. leaking an editor's country of residence, if they edit a rarely-viewed page that no-one else views withing a reporting interval), but those could presumably be handled, e.g. by only geolocating a statistical sample of all requests, and by lumping together statistics for rarely-viewed pages into a single "other" group.

I suspect the main question is simply whether Wikimedia, as a mostly volunteer-run non-profit supported by donations, would really consider all the work needed to provide such statistics worthwhile.  Still, I don't suppose it could hurt to ask.